# VSTO Add-Ins Keep Disappearing From Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

everyone. I'm working on a project that involves VSTO add-ins for Excel, using C# as the programming language. On one computer, the add-ins keep disappearing without any apparent reason. Every day, the user has to re-enable the add-ins frequently by going to **Options -> COM Add-Ins.** Other users who are using the same add-ins don't seem to have this issue.

I've added exception handling code at all possible places within the project to prevent exceptions and errors from affecting the add-ins' behavior and to prevent Excel from disabling them. However, this effort hasn't resolved the issue. I've also implemented logging in the project, and upon reviewing the log file, I found only one error logged in the past two months. At this point, I'm unsure why the Excel application is disabling the add-ins and how to fix this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume OS is Windows.

1. Research Operating system logs for error messages.
2. Ensure the user have no problem with its user data, which can cause Windows to recreate the user profile every user login.
3. Check Excel security settings.